# MySQL if field equals X show it as Y

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new here and to MySQL. I tried googling the question but found only `SELECT column FROM table AS t` statements, which I believe it is not what I need.

I have a column named "active" in a table named "products". it's optional values are `-1, 0, 1`.

I am using `SELECT active FROM products`. It shows the table as it is but I want to make it show `0` where the value equals `-1` without changing the original value.

Can this be done in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN active = -1 THEN 0
               ELSE active
        END active_2
FROM products;
```

or `IF`:

```
SELECT *, IF(active=-1, 0, active) AS active_2
FROM products;
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, does one of them considered better practice? why?

Comment: @omer CASE  expression will work across multiple RDBMSes(Oracle,SQL Server, PostgreSQL). `IF` is MySQL specific. I suggest to use `CASE`

Comment: What does the active_2 means?

Comment: @omer I used `SELECT *` that is why I add alias for expression. You could name it as you wish or `SELECT col_name1, col_name2, CASE ... END AS active FROM ..`

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot :D